# Diacríticas desde archivos cmd.bat

Tags: vb.net, msdos

intento escribir en un archivo de texto, Con **Vb.Net** los paths del los archivos que hay en un directorio con los siguientes comandos ms-dos.

```
RunCmd("cd " & FileIO.SpecialDirectories.Temp & "&c:&dir", "/s /b>""" & pths & "\utmp.txt" & """&exit", True)
```

...Pero el resultado escrito, en el archivo de texto (utmp.txt), no es como espero. Pues algunos de esos paths contienen acentos, ñ, otras diacríticas y o símbolos accii (**·**).

Como puedo usar el código anterior para que se escriban correctamente las palabras en el archivo de texto?

Gracias por su ayuda.

***Edito:***

gracias @Mateo por la ayuda. Pero no funciona con lo siguiente

Escribo la función

```
    Sub RunCmd(cmmd As String, argm As String, prnt As Boolean)
    Dim c As New Process()
    Dim p As New ProcessStartInfo()

    p.UseShellExecute = False
    p.RedirectStandardInput = True
    p.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    p.RedirectStandardError = True
    p.CreateNoWindow = True

    p.Arguments = " " + If(prnt = True, "/K", "/C") + " " + cmmd + " " + argm
    p.FileName = "cmd.exe"
    p.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden

    c.StartInfo.StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(65001)

    c.StartInfo = p

    c.Start()
    c.WaitForExit()
End Sub

Sub Button1_Click() Handles Button1.Click
    RunCmd("cd " & FileIO.SpecialDirectories.Temp & "&c:&chcp 65001&dir", "/s /b>""" & pths & "\utmp.txt" & """&chcp 850&exit", True)
End Sub
```

**EDITO (23/06/2023 - 23:35)**
Con lo siguiente funciona...

```
        Try
        Dim p As New Process()
        Dim sw As StreamWriter
        Dim sr As StreamReader
        Dim psI As New ProcessStartInfo("cmd")
        psI.UseShellExecute = False
        psI.RedirectStandardInput = True
        psI.RedirectStandardOutput = True
        psI.RedirectStandardError = True
        psI.CreateNoWindow = True
        p.StartInfo = psI
        p.StartInfo.StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252)
        p.Start()
        sw = p.StandardInput
        sr = p.StandardOutput
        sw.AutoFlush = True
        sw.WriteLine("áéíóúñ")
        sw.Close()
        Rtb1.Text = sr.ReadToEnd()
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
```

...Solo hay que crear la function para hacerlo mas cómodo.
**Fin De la edición**

Comment: Bienvenido a la informática, donde escribir en español con acentos y eñes es un suplicio. Precisamente por eso la mayoría de nosotros usamos nombres de archivos sin caracteres especiales, espacios ni eñes. A la hora de trabajar te hacen la vida muy fácil :P Miedo me da el día que la gente empiece a usar emojis para nombrar sus fotos... "yo y los ñeñes xd (emojiSonriendo) 2035-05-15.jpeg"

Comment: Prueba a cambiar la página de códigos primero con `chcp 65001`